# Java - Mac OS - GDAL/OGR missing libraries

Tags: gdal, ogr, java, esri-geodatabase, macos

I'm trying to read/access a geodatabase (.gdb folder) for extracting some data. I can access the database from terminal using

```
>ogrinfo test.gdb.zip
```

and as result i get

```
using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
Group separated:
  Layer: Floor (3D TIN)
  Layer: Wall (3D Multi Polygon)
  Layer: Roof (3D Multi Polygon)
Group solid:
  Layer: Roof_solid (3D Multi Polygon)
  Layer: Building_solid (3D TIN)
```

So GDAL is installed successfully in my computer.

Then, I need to automate the process inside a Java program. When I run the following block of commands ( for looking up which driver I can access, I need to access openFileGDB)

```
 OGRDataStoreFactory factory = new JniOGRDataStoreFactory();
        Set<String> drivers = factory.getAvailableDrivers();
        for (String driver : drivers) {
            System.out.println(driver);
        }
```

I obtain the following as error in console

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path: [/Users/steve/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.lambda$initAnimator$5(PSurfaceJOGL.java:477)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

It seems that a `gdalalljni` library is missing, it is two days that I cannot solve this problem.

There's some that can access GDAL Java library with MacOS?

Comment: Install the gdal java bindings?

Comment: I tried but i could not find any working doc about that